# How can I find the indices where two arrays differ in value?

Tags: perl

I would like to find out which element has changed between two arrays that contains same data inside it.

```
@prev=("0","1","0","1");
@curr=("0","1","0","0");
```

From the above two arrays clearly the last element of the array has changed.

How will I know that only a particular element has changed and rest all of them should not have changed, given that I know which index of the array should change?

Answer (score 2):

To find out the indices where the values have changed:

```
my @indices_of_change = grep { $prev[$_] ne $curr[$_] } 0 .. $#prev;
```

e.g. with:

```
my @prev = ( 0, 1, 0, 1 );
my @curr = ( 0, 1, 0, 0 );  # @indices_of_change == ( 3 );
```

Of course, there are several caveats attached:

- Are `@curr` and `@prev` supposed to be the same length? What is the expected behavior if they are not?
- The context of DWIM needs to be clarified. Are strings expected to be inside the array(s)? Is `'00'` supposed to equal to `'0'`?

Comment: @monucool Don't use all caps. It looks like you are shouting.

Comment: sorry..will take care next time.

Comment: is your syntax currect what is the trailing 0 .. ??

Comment: @monucool : Yes it is. `0 .. $#prev` is a list of all possible indices contained by `@prev`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind me pimping my own module, this is exactly why [Array::Compare](https://metacpan.org/module/Array%3a%3aCompare) was written.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.010;
use Array::Compare;

my @prev = qw(0 1 0 1);
my @curr = qw(0 1 0 0);

my $cmp = Array::Compare->new;

my @diffs = $cmp->full_compare(\@prev, \@curr);

say "Difference at these indexes: @diffs";
```

Comment: Would you still use `Moose` if you had to rewrite this module?

Comment: Absolutely. I use Moose whenever I can.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the zip function from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aMoreUtils) to allow comparison like this. Using `zip` has the advantage that it works with arrays that are not of equal length.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw/zip/;
my @changed = 
    map { $_[0] != $_[1] }
        zip @prev, @curr;
```

Comment: i get the following error-rray found where operator expected at printing.pl line 10, at end of line
        (Missing operator before ?)
Not enough arguments for List::MoreUtils::mesh at printing.pl line 10, near "@prev @curr"
syntax error at printing.pl line 10, near "@prev @curr"
Execution of printing.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Add a comma between `@prev` and `@curr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Data::Difference](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDifference) to compare arrays. And it's quite easy to mangle the returned diff to your needs:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Difference qw(data_diff);
use Data::Dumper;
my @prev = ( "0", "1", "0", "1" );
my @curr = ( "0", "1", "0", "0" );

my @diff = data_diff ( \@prev, \@curr );
my @indices_of_change = map { @{ $_->{ 'path' } } } @diff;
print Dumper ( \@indices_of_change );
```

Comment: how to get the Difference.pm module.?

Comment: There are several ways to install modules. See [the instructions on cpan.org](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html).